# Is There a First-Order Logic Formula for Describing a Finite, Full Tree with Leaves at Even Levels?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is about first-order logic.

Let the dictionary $ \Sigma $ consist of a single two-place relation symbol $\text{Child} $ i.e. $\Sigma=\{\text{Child} (\cdot,\cdot )\} $. A structure $ \mathcal{M} $ over $\Sigma$  is called a "tree" if its interpretation as a graph is a tree. Furthermore, a tree is "full" if every non-leaf node has exactly 2 children (sons). Lastly, the "level" of a node in the tree is defined as its distance from the root.

> **My question is:** Does there exist a first-order logic formula $\phi $
> such that for every structure $ \mathcal{M},  \phi $ holds in $
>  \mathcal{M}$ if and only if $ \mathcal{M} $ is a finite, full tree
> where all leaves are at even levels?

My intuition says there is no such a formal, since "properties of properties" is a bit out of the scope of *FOL*.
As I know, proving *"there is no such a formal $\phi$ such that.."* start by by assuming that exist $\phi$, then construct some unsatisfiable formula's set $\Gamma$ where $\phi \in \Gamma$, and then following  *Compactness* proof that any$\Delta\subset\Gamma$ is satisfiable. and I'm struggling to come up with such a $\Gamma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that such a $ \phi $ exists that characterizes finite, full trees where all leaves are at even levels. We will construct a set $ \Gamma $ such that $ \phi \in \Gamma $ and show that $ \Gamma $ is not satisfiable, thereby reaching a contradiction.

Let $ \Gamma = \{ \phi \} \cup \{ \psi_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $, where $ \psi_n $ asserts that *there exists a node at the $n$-th level.*

Formally, $ \psi_n $ could be something like:

$$ \psi_n = \exists x_1 \exists x_2 \ldots \exists x_{n} \left( \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1} \text{Child}(x_i, x_{i+1})  \land \underbrace{\forall y(\lnot \text{Child}(y, x_{1}))}_{\text{root}}  \right)$$

###### Claim 1: Every finite subset $ \Delta \subseteq \Gamma $ is satisfiable.

Proof: Any finite subset $ \Delta $ will contain $ \phi $ and finitely many $ \psi_{2k} $ for some finitely . We can always construct a finite, where all leaves are at even levels that satisfies $ \phi $ and all the $ \psi_n $ in $ \Delta $, thus by compactness we have that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

###### Claim 2: $ \Gamma $ itself is not satisfiable.

Proof: Assume that $ \Gamma $ is satisfiable. Then there exists a structure $ \mathcal{M} $ that satisfies $ \phi $ and all $ \psi_{2n}$. This would mean $ \mathcal{M} $ is a finite, full tree with some rank $2k$, but  $ \psi_{2k+2}$ is also true in $ \mathcal{M} $, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, if all models of a sentence $\phi$ are finite, then there is a uniform bound on the size of models of $\phi$ (by compactness). This rules out the possibility of such a sentence existing.

Beyond that though, even if you ask a weaker question, specifically whether there is a sentence $\phi$ such that finite models of $\phi$ are precisely the full trees where all leaves are at even levels, then the answer is still no.

You can formalize being a tree and fullness as first-order properties, but the difficulty is with evenness. Let $F$ be the collection of 'fully' full binary trees of finite height (i.e., full trees in which all leaves are at the same level). One can show using an [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game) that for any sentence $\phi$, $\phi$ is satisfied by either only finitely many members of $F$ or all but finitely many members of $F$. In particular, no sentence picks out precisely the elements of $F$ with even height.